# How to avoid JObject.Parse parsing a DateTime, and instead just get the raw string?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a JSON data like below, when I read the DateTime tag, it is internally converted to {2/11/2022 6:56:17 AM}. I need data to be read in the string format, same as data available in the JSON

Code Snippet:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var dateTime = jsonObject["LastModified"]["DateTime"]; // output = {2/11/2022 6:56:17 AM}, but i need "2022-02-11T06:56:17.143Z".
```

```
{"LastModified": {
            "Username": "Philips Administrator",
            "DateTime": "2022-02-11T06:56:17.143Z"
        }
}
```

Comment: i would deserialize into a Date type then you can control the ToString() using a format

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: If you don't want the value to be implicitly converted into a `DateTime` at all, you can disable that via `JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling`

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's not the issue, he wants the raw string from the JSON, but Json.net is interpreting it as a DateTime since it detects it can parse it as such. Basically he wants Json.net to **not** interpret it as a DateTime and instead just return the original string directly.

Answer (score 5):

As others point out a DateTime has no format. When you convert it to a string you can format it however you like. If you really, really want to treat it as a string, you can do as Jon Skeet suggests:

```cs
var jsonText = @"{""LastModified"": {
            ""Username"": ""Philips Administrator"",
            ""DateTime"": ""2022-02-11T06:56:17.143Z""
        }
}";
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
};
JObject jsonObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, settings);
var dateTime = jsonObject["LastModified"]["DateTime"];
```

It also works with dates like "932 AD, a little before lunch time".